# Does Here charge for storage usage of spreadsheets sent to geocode in batch?

Tags: geocoding, here-api

Here charges a transaction for each geocoded line. But one thing is not clear in the documentation: will I also be charged for the storage usage of the files I send?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because pricing question are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

The are no additional costs for any storage in that case. This is only transaction based.